# Criar usuario pelo Basic4Android

Tags: android

Como criar uma tela de login pelo Basic4Android para cadastrar usuários num banco de dados MySQL?

Procurei explicação e não achei nenhuma, alguém pode me ajuda?

Comment: preciso que o usuario crie seu cadastro com Nome, Salario, E-mail no android e cadastre no banco de dados mysql